# C++ Code to Generate Permutations

Tags: c++, permutation

I am trying to code a program that will generate permutations with the characters repeated. So far I have 3 loops:

```
for (int f = 0; f < n; f++)
    for (int s = 0; s < n; s++)
        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++)
            newString = characters[f] + characters[s] + characters[t];
```

This approach lacks generality in that it requires me to know the permutation length beforehand.

Example: ABC

```
AAA AAB AAC ABA ABB ABC ACA ACB ACC 

BAA BAB BAC BBA BBB BBC BCA BCB BCC

CAA CAB CAC CBA CBB CBC CCA CCB CCC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know any of the math for it, I am just starting algorithmic programming. This is for the USACO training pages.

Comment: you do not need any math for it. Also if you do not know anything to start solving problems, does not it sound obvious to start learning some prerequisites before doing harder things?

Comment: I am still in high school. Prerequisites?

Comment: Yes, if you told you do not know any math to solve problem - learn math and then start solving problems. The argument that you are in high school is absolutely irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't trying to waste your time. I just don't have the resources to learn it by myself. An aggressive tone isn't necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69053/discussion-between-sidy3d-and-salvador-dali).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need permutations (your example is not permutations), C++ Standard Library has a perfect function for that - [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

```
string s("ABC");
do {
    cout << s << endl;
} while (next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

Note that the range must be sorted coming into the first iteration of this loop in order to generate a complete list of permutations ([Demo #1](http://ideone.com/hZxzl3)).

Your example produces all combinations with repetitions from a set of characters. You can do it with nested loops, like you did, or with recursion:

```
void combinations(const string& s, vector<int>& pos, int n) {
    if (n == s.size()) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
            cout << s[pos[i]];
        }
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != s.size(); i++) {
        pos[n] = i;
        combinations(s, pos, n+1);
    }
}
```

[Demo #2.](http://ideone.com/mrkSfU)

Comment: Doesn't work. It only returns ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA

Comment: @sidy3d That's because I thought you wanted permutations. I edited to show how to produce combinations with repetitions.