# How to efficiently permute an array in-place (using std::swap)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++17, permutation

How can I apply a permutation in-place? My permutations are effectively `size_t[]` where `perm[i]` represents the target index for an input index `i`.

I know how to apply a permutation if I have an input and output array:

```cpp
struct Permutation {
    std::vector<size_t> perm;

    template <typename T>
    void apply(const T in[], T out[]) const
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            out[i] = std::move(in[perm[i]]);
        }
    }

}
```

However, I would like to do this with only one array, similar to how `std::sort` works, so just using `std::swap`. My idea so far is:

```cpp
struct Permutation {
    std::vector<size_t> perm;

    template <typename T>
    void apply(T data[]) const
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            std::swap(data[i], data[perm[i]]);
        }
    }

}
```

But this wouldn't work. For example:

```
Permutation perm = {2, 1, 0};
char data[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
perm.apply(data);

// because I swap indices 0 and 2 twice, I end up with the input array
data == {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

So how do I correctly permute an array in-place? It is okay if additional memory is allocated, as long as this happens in a pre-computation step when the `Permutation` is constructed. I want the in-place permutation to happen fast and from the looks of it, demanding that **no** additional memory is allocated at all will lead to some severe performance sacrifices.

I am specifically referencing [Algorithm to apply permutation in constant memory space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16501424), where **all** of the provided answers either cheat by using negative-integer space to avoid an allocation or enter "nasty" nested loops which blow up the time complexity to O(n²).

#### Edits

Please pay attention before suggesting `std::next_permutation`. I am not trying to generate all possible permutations, which I could do with `std::next_permutation`. I am instead trying to apply a single particular permutation to an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Code to Generate Permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007090/c-code-to-generate-permutations)

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni no, it obviously does not, see the previous comment.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in O(n) time without additional memory. And in the worst case this additional memory is actually a new array, just like your output array.

Comment: You need to extract [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) from your permutation and apply them.

Comment: @Dialecticus I wouldn't be so quick to make this statement. Permutations consist of multiple cycles and at least each individual cycle can be applied by continuously swapping.

Comment: True, but you have to save the information about which items are already swapped. Additional memory.

Comment: I assume that this is correct: https://medium.com/@kevingxyz/permutation-in-place-8528581a5553

Comment: @YvesDaoust yeah that looks like it might work, it's just unfortunate that it resorts to a nested loop.

Comment: I guess that an efficient solution is presented in Knuth, working in linear time. It uses the fact that any permutation is made of a number of cycles, and cycles are easily permuted.

Comment: Just check every time if `perm[i] < i` to avoid duplicated swaps

Comment: @pptaszni This doesn't work. The (now deleted) comment mentioned a sufficient counter-example: It wouldn't work e.g. for `{ 2, 0, 1 }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm to apply permutation in constant memory space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501424/algorithm-to-apply-permutation-in-constant-memory-space)

Comment: @pptaszni not quite, I have edited the question to make it more distinct from what you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint to find the cycles and permute each cycle worked for me. To sum up my approach, I find the start indices of all cycles in the constructor.
Then, in `apply()`, I permute each cycle by just repeatedly using `std::swap`.

```cpp
struct Permutation {
private:
    /// The single vector which stores both the permutation
    /// AND the indices of the cycles starts.
    std::vector<size_t> perm;
    /// The size of the permutation / index of first cycle index.
    size_t permSize;

public:
    Permutation(std::vector<size_t> table)
        : perm{std::move(table)}, permSize{perm.size()} {
        findCycles();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void apply(T data[]) const {
        for (size_t cycle = permSize; cycle < perm.size(); ++cycle) {
            const size_t start = perm[cycle];
            for (size_t prev = start, next = perm[prev];
                 next != start;
                 prev = next, next = perm[next]) {
                std::swap(data[prev], data[next]);
            }
        }
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return permSize;
    }

private:
    void findCycles();
}
```

`findCycles()` is also easy to implement, but requires the temporary allocation of a bit-vector.

```cpp
void Permutation::findCycles() {
    std::vector<bool> visited(size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
        if (visited[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        for (size_t j = i; not visited[j]; ) {

            visited[j] = true;
            j = perm[j];
        }
        perm.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In worst case there will be n/2 cycles, each of length 2. Vector of size n/2 is an additional memory. It is less than the original output vector of size n, but you pay the price of having to run twice through the input vector. Time is usually more of an issue than memory, but it's finally up to you to figure out what you have and what you need.

Comment: @Dialecticus thanks but the worst case is an identity permutation, where there are N cycles each of length 1. So the worst case is doubling the input vector in size. I have benchmarked both `apply` methods and the in-place method was almost exactly twice as slow. So there really isn't much of a point in using it, unless one is working with gigabytes of data where caching becomes problematic.